# .xlsx file in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have some code who works in `netbeans` for reading .xlsx file. I am trying to implement that in Android Studio but has not succeeded to reach my .xlsx file: I have put the path "C\etc\etc\" and it did not work.

I copied the file to `drawable` folder and set the following variable but it still did not work:

```
String filename = "renk hex.xlsx";
```

Where I should put this .xlsx file in order to reach it?

I do not have errors in code and my app on `genymotion` stops to work when I call the class who is responsible for reading this file.

Here is my code :

```
      String filename = "renk hex.xlsx";
    List sheetData = new ArrayList();         // dataItem


    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
       XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            List data = new ArrayList();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                data.add(cell);
            }

            sheetData.add(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

log :

```
                Process: hesh.ballc, PID: 3774
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Thanks

Comment: If it stops working, there's likely an exception somewhere. Please share where your code is breaking...

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Here is my code

Comment: @huse_ng please add your logcat exception output, it would help much more in finding exactly where it is breaking as opposed through picking through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into `assets` folder (src/main/assets) and read like this

`InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);`

Or in the 'raw' folder and read like this:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
```